# How to disable beep on phonegap plugin barcodescanner ? (meteor and cordova)

Tags: cordova, meteor, barcode-scanner, beep

I'm writing an meteor app using the phonegap plugin barcodeScanner https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner everything is working fine except that i don't find a way to disable the "beep" sound that is launch after a barcode scan success. Does anyone find a way on how to do that ?

Comment: Take a look in [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues/54). It seems to be possible to overwrite the platforms/android/res/raw/beep.ogg with a silent ogg.

Comment: I finaly found how to do that by just putting a new beep.ogg (silent of course) in a special top folder that meteor provide.

So first u have to create a folder named cordova-build-override, then inside create a platforms/android/res/raw folder and place ur new beep.ogg inside.

this url gave me the idea : https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-sounds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner#using-the-plugin) shows that a `disableSuccessBeep` parameter can be passed to disable the beep.

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
  function (result) {
    // Do something with the barcode
  },
  function (error) {
    // Handle error
  },
  {
    disableSuccessBeep: true
  }
);
```

Note that the `disableSuccessBeep` parameter only disables the beep on iOS. For other platforms that beep, you can upload a silent sound file as @Phonolog pointed out in the comments:

> Take a look in [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues/54). It seems to be possible to overwrite the platforms/android/res/raw/beep.ogg with a silent ogg.